# Open, edit and save an excel

Tags: python, excel, pycharm, openpyxl

I want to open an excel file and edit the file. After the edit I want to save the file.
Please see below for my current progress. Unfortunately I get an error. I don't know why. Could you please tell me the error and help me to fix it ? Thank you in advance for your supprt. Looking forward to reading your answer.

```
import openpyxl as oxl

path = '///My Documents/Python/'
fileName = "test.xlsx"    

# name of files to read from
r_filenameXLSX = path+fileName

# open the Excel file
xlsx_wb = oxl.load_workbook(filename=r_filenameXLSX)

# names of all the sheets in the workbook
sheets = xlsx_wb.get_sheet_names()

# extract the worksheet
xlsx_ws = xlsx_wb[sheets[0]]

labels = [cell.value for cell in xlsx_ws.rows[0]]

data = []  # list to hold the data

for row in xlsx_ws.rows[1:]:
    data.append([cell.value for cell in row])


print([item[labels.index('Content')] for item in data[0:10]])
```

Error message:

```
C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Test/Main.py:29: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames).
  sheets = xlsx_wb.get_sheet_names()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Test/Main.py", line 34, in <module>
    labels = [cell.value for cell in xlsx_ws.rows[0]]
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `ws.rows` is a generator so you can't write `ws.rows[0]` For more information please read up on Python generators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ws.rows` is a generator, so you cannot iterate, you can call a next() on that generator to get value,

otherwise use as below

```
wb = oxl.load_workbook(filename=r_filenameXLSX)
ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]

labels = [cell.value for cell in next(ws.rows)]
print(labels)

# 'data' contains data starting from second row 
data = [[ws.cell(i,j).value for j in range(1, ws.max_column+1)] for i in range(2, ws.max_row+1)]

print([item[labels.index('Content')] for item in data[0:10]])
```

Best way to load an excel sheet to a table is using [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r_filenameXLSX, sheet_name='your_sheet_name_here')
print(df['Content'])
```

Comment: Pandas is great, but not always want people need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for the help!